# OR condition implementation using logic:equal

Tags: java, struts, equals

I am new to struts and I was thinking if we can implement `OR` and `AND` conditions with struts `logic:equal`? if not then what are the alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

for AND like 
    if(Column1 == "1" && Column2 == "2")
    {
      ....
    }

you can use :

```
<logic:equal name="urList" property="Column1" value="1">
  <logic:equal name="urList" property="Column2" value="2">
  doSomeThing
  </logic:equal>
</logic:equal>
```

or for 'OR' :

```
<logic:equal name="urList" property="Column1" value="1">
  doSomeThing
</logic:equal>
<logic:equal name="urList" property="Column2" value="2">
  doSomeThing
</logic:equal>
```

sry for bad english.

Comment: Unfortunately this `OR` implementation does `doSomeThing` twice if both conditions are met

Comment: how can u do, to amke it doSomeThing ( in OR condition) but just once?

Comment: @PetrÚjezdský ty

Comment: You have to negate the first statement in the second one using `logic:notEqual` and then nest your "OR" branch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use EL with Strut's taglib. You can also use JSTL (c:if in this case).

Answer (score -1):

use JSP scriptlet instead of logic: equals

```
if(string.equals("Rejected") || string.equals("selected")){
do someting
}
```

In JSP:

```
<%if(string.equals("Rejected") || string.equals("selected")){
do someting
}%>
```

Comment: Never use scriptlets, it's an antipattern